# Adding a new field to a JSON object with "lens"

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

Please consider the following program:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import qualified Data.Aeson


json :: Data.Aeson.Value
json =
  maybe undefined id (Data.Aeson.decode "{\"a\":\"1\"}")

addAField :: State Data.Aeson.Value ()
addAField =
  assign (key "b" . _String) "2"

main =
  print (execState addAField json)
```

It results in the following output:

```
Object (fromList [("a",String "1")])
```

How can I update the `addAField` function to make the program produce the following output:

```
Object (fromList [("a",String "1"), ("b",String "2")])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can come up with involves a direct addressing of JSON values:

```
addAField :: State Data.Aeson.Value ()
addAField =
  assign (_Object . at "b") (Just (Data.Aeson.String "2"))
```